# Odd access violation reading error / glDrawArrays usage

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering

I'm not sure if this belongs here or in graphichs progamming.....I am getting a really annoying access violation reading error and I can't figure out why. What I am trying to do is to refactor a keyframing function (calculate the mid position between two vertices positions). This function compiles and works fine

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    for(int i = 0; i < numTriangles; i++) {
        MD2Triangle* triangle = triangles + i;
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            MD2Vertex* v1 = frame1->vertices + triangle->vertices[j];
            MD2Vertex* v2 = frame2->vertices + triangle->vertices[j];
            Vec3f pos = v1->pos * (1 - frac) + v2->pos * frac;
            Vec3f normal = v1->normal * (1 - frac) + v2->normal * frac;
            if (normal[0] == 0 && normal[1] == 0 && normal[2] == 0) {
                normal = Vec3f(0, 0, 1);
            }
            glNormal3f(normal[0], normal[1], normal[2]);

            MD2TexCoord* texCoord = texCoords + triangle->texCoords[j];
            glTexCoord2f(texCoord->texCoordX, texCoord->texCoordY);
            glVertex3f(pos[0], pos[1], pos[2]);
        }
    }
glEnd();
```

Here the function calculates the positions and draws them. What I'd like to do is to calculate all positions before hand, store them in a Vertex array and then draw them.
If I try and remove it and replace this bloc in the exact same part of the program with the following

```
int vCount = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < numTriangles; i++) {
        MD2Triangle* triangle = triangles + i;
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            MD2Vertex* v1 = frame1->vertices + triangle->vertices[j];
            MD2Vertex* v2 = frame2->vertices + triangle->vertices[j];
            Vec3f pos = v1->pos * (1 - frac) + v2->pos * frac;
            Vec3f normal = v1->normal * (1 - frac) + v2->normal * frac;
            if (normal[0] == 0 && normal[1] == 0 && normal[2] == 0) {
                normal = Vec3f(0, 0, 1);
            }

            indices[vCount] = normal[0];
            vCount++;
            indices[vCount] = normal[1];
            vCount++;
            indices[vCount] = normal[2];
            vCount++;

            MD2TexCoord* texCoord = texCoords + triangle->texCoords[j];
            indices[vCount] = texCoord->texCoordX;
            vCount++;
            indices[vCount] = texCoord->texCoordY;
            vCount++;

            indices[vCount] = pos[0];
            vCount++;
            indices[vCount] = pos[1];
            vCount++;
            indices[vCount] = pos[2];
            vCount++;
        }

    }
```

I get access violation error "Unhandled exception at 0x01455626 in Graphics_template_1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xed5243c0" pointing at line 7

```
Vec3f pos = v1->pos * (1 - frac) + v2->pos * frac;
```

where the two Vs seems to have no value in the debugger.... Till this point the function behaves in exactly the same way as the one above, I don't understand why this happens?

EDIT ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Thank you Werner for spotting that the issue was the array initialization! As per your advice I refactored the function using std:vector containers and made the drawing use glDrawArrays instead of immediate mode.... But instead of an improvement in performance the framerate is a lot lower than before! Am I using this function right/efficiently? This is the refactored draw function:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < numTriangles; i++) {
        MD2Triangle* triangle = triangles + i;
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            MD2Vertex* v1 = frame1->vertices + triangle->vertices[j];
            MD2Vertex* v2 = frame2->vertices + triangle->vertices[j];
            Vec3f pos = v1->pos * (1 - frac) + v2->pos * frac;
            Vec3f normal = v1->normal * (1 - frac) + v2->normal * frac;
            if (normal[0] == 0 && normal[1] == 0 && normal[2] == 0) {
                normal = Vec3f(0, 0, 1);
            }


            normals.push_back(normal[0]);
            normals.push_back(normal[1]);
            normals.push_back(normal[2]);

            MD2TexCoord* texCoord = texCoords + triangle->texCoords[j];
            textCoords.push_back(texCoord->texCoordX);
            textCoords.push_back(texCoord->texCoordY);

            vertices.push_back(pos[0]);
            vertices.push_back(pos[1]);
            vertices.push_back(pos[2]);
        }

    }


    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, &normals[0]);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, &textCoords[0]); 
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &vertices[0]);



    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size()/3);


    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);  // disable vertex arrays
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

    vertices.clear();
    textCoords.clear();
    normals.clear();
```

Is there something extra that I am doing here? Cos this is really meant to be more efficient that glBegin()/End(), right?

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: What about the glBegin() and glEnd()? I'm not good with OpenGL, but maybe that initializes some memory the vertices are stored in?

Comment: Since we can't see any self-contained example, we can only guess, which leads us to `MD2Vertex* v1 = frame1->vertices + triangle->vertices[j];` probably (or v2) resulting in a wrong pointer. Since we can not see how the values that are used in this line came to existence, there is not much we can guess, only that maybe something is uninitialized.

Comment: I did actually try that to no avail...glBegin/End shouldnt be needed when drawing from a buffer I understand.... but thanks for yuor inpup!

Comment: Did you try to compile your code with all warnings and debugging information enabled (on Linux, that would mean `g++ -Wall -g`) and to debug your program (on linux, with the `gdb` debugger, and perhaps the   `ddd` front-end to it)?

Comment: @LiMuBei That is a nonsense. glBegin and glEnd delimit the vertices that define a primitive or a group of like primitives.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch yes, nothing is mentioned about that section on compilation... I have also added info on the structs and where they are created...

Comment: What values are in `endFrame` and `startFrame`?

Comment: @LiMuBei: No it doesn't, and the Access Violation happens on the MD2 structures, which are independent of OpenGL.

Comment: @VJo ` model->startFrame = 0;
 model->endFrame = numFrames - 1;`, these are set up when the model is initialised, before the drawing calls, where numFrames is loaded from the file...

Comment: Does it crash when you do not write to indices? Did you check that you are not writing past the end of indices (overwriting your other data structs)?

Comment: @WernerHenze Wow, well spotted. It seems in fact that removing the lines where I write to indices does not cause the error! What would be the best way of declaring/initializing the indices for the glDrawElements call? Currently I have `GLfloat indices[];` but the size of the array really depends on how many vertices the model has, which is not known until the model is loaded after initialization...

Comment: Thanks Werner, have ticked your answer as it solved the access violation error.... I have posted my re factored function above; it turns out to perform even worse than the original one... maybe I am not using it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, let's make it an answer. The guess was:

> Does it crash when you do not write to indices? Did you check that you
>   are not writing past the end of indices (overwriting your other data
>   structs)?

Your reply wass, that you create an array GLfloat indices[] since you do not know the array size in advance.

The best (performing) solution would be to calculate the array size in advance and create the array approriately.

```
GLfloat *indices = new GLfloat[calculated_number_of_elements];
...use array...;
delete [] indices;
```

Better yet you can create a std::vector:

```
std::vector<GLfloat> indices(calculated_number_of_elements);
```

The vector also has the advantage that it can be resized dynamically.